# What can be said about an infinitely differentiable function whose Taylor series diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

What can be said in general of an infinitely smooth function whose Taylor series diverges?  According to [Borel Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) it is possible to construct such but what kind of property have those special functions ?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic) for an example.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what types of properties you're interested in? The questions is rather vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinitely differentiable but not analytic functions are not "special" at all. In a certain sense, most $C^\infty$ functions are nowhere analytic. See, for example, the [presentation](http://analytic.wmi.amu.edu.pl/media/esser_slides.pdf) *About generic properties of "nowhere analyticity"* by Esser (joint work with Bastin and Nicolay).

Due to their ubiquity, non-analytic functions do not have any special properties: it's the analytic functions that are special. Of course, one can state the negation  of any sufficient condition for analyticity. For example: every extension of a non-analytic function at $x_0$ to a neighborhood of $x_0$ is $\mathbb C$ will fail to be complex-differentiable.

Comment: Nice slides. Thanks! I've been compiling information on this topic for a bit now, and they list several references and a few results I was not aware of.