# Does the Taylor series of an infinitely differentiable function converge; and if yes, does it converge to the function?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, analyticity

I have googled it, but I am not satisfied with those.

So my questions are:

> 1. Let $D$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a **infinitely differentiable** function.
>
> Fix $x_0\in D$
>
> Then, does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ converge on some neightborhood of $x_0$?

Secondly,

> 1. Let $D$ and $f$ be the domain and function illustrated as above.
>
> Fix $x_0 \in D$
>
> Assume, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ converge on $W\cap D$ where $W$ is some neightborhood $W$ of $x_0$.
>
> Then, does this series coincide with $f$ on $W\cap D$?

Comment: There's an entire Wikipedia article on the subject: [Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function). What is unsatisfactory about it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/every-power-series-is-the-taylor-series-of-some-c-infty-function

Comment: No. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/620290/462) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/906298/462).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not every infinitely differentiable function possess a power series. For instance the function $ e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} $ does not possess a power series centered at the point $x=0$.

Comment: Specifically, this does not answer the first question, but does provide a counterexample for the second question.  That function has a Taylor series at $x=0$ with radius of convergence $\infty$, but it doesn't converge to the function except at $0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Leave the OP take his time to read my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor's theorem says that every function $f(x)$ that has $n$ derivatives in some neighborhood of point $x_0$, is equal to the series (for every $x$ in that neighborhood)

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n + R_n(x)$$

Where $R_n$ is the remainder, 
$$
R_n(x) = \frac{(x-x_0)^{n}}{n!}f^{(n)}(\xi),  
$$

Where $\xi$ is some number between $x_0$ and $x$. Note that this remainder term is the just the generalization of the Lagrange mean value theorem, i.e. for n=1, 
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f'(\xi)
$$

Now  if you let $n \to \infty$, the function will be equal to the infinite series (in a neighborhood of $x_0$)
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n
$$

Only if a neighborhood of point $x_0$ exists, such that for all x in that neighborhood the remainder term tends to zero

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}R_n(x) = 0
$$

If this condition is satisfied the function is analytic at $x_0$.

You can easily prove that the remainder tends to zero if you can bound every derivative of your function, this is true for the sine function for example, for all $n$

$$
|\sin (x)^{(n)}| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(x-x_0)^{n}}{n!}|\sin (\xi)^{(n)}| \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(x-x_0)^{n}}{n!} = 0
$$

Thus $\sin$ is an analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

Borel's theorem (You can read about it [here](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~badam/publications/borel.pdf)) provides strong counterexamples to your question.